# How does hadoop configuration work

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I see we can configure different parameters in hadoop clusters. Bit confused if we configure master, these configurations are replicated in client nodes? Or every nodes should be configured separately?

For eg, like setting block size as 128MB in master, so all client nodes will have 128MB or since those nodes are not configured will it be in default value 64MB? If master setting is used then for configs where system parameters are considered like no of cores how to handle those?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration in Hadoop is more complex. Actually, hadoop lets the API users to decide how to use the configuration.

For example, let's discovery how the file block size is determined. The file block size uses the value of `fs.local.block.size` in the configuration.

### fs.local.block.size is not set in the configuration in the client side

This situation is that `conf.get("fs.local.block.size");` returns `null` in the client side.

If you use the following codes (the codes is in your client) to create a File in HDFS,

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
FSDataOutputStream output = fs.create(new Path("/new/file/in/hdfs"));
// write your data to output...
```

Then `fs.local.block.size` use the default value, which is 32MB ([32 * 1024 * 1024)](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java#FileSystem.getDefaultBlockSize%28%29).

However, if you write a MapReduce job to output some files (I assume you use [TextOutputFormat](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextOutputFormat.java?av=h#107), some custom output format may change the following behaviour), the file block size is determined by the configuration of the TaskTracker. So in this situation, if your configuration is inconsistent in different nodes, you may find that the MapReduce output files have different block sizes.

### fs.local.block.size is set in the configuration in the client side

This situation is that you can use `conf.get("fs.local.block.size");` to get the value of `fs.local.block.size` in the client side.

If you use the following codes (the codes is in your client) to create a File in HDFS,

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
FSDataOutputStream output = fs.create(new Path("/new/file/in/hdfs"));
// write your data to output...
```

The `fs.local.block.size` is `conf.get("fs.local.block.size")`. [FileSystem.create](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java#FileSystem.create%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29)

However, if you write a MapReduce job to output some files, it's a little complex.

If in one TaskTracker, `fs.local.block.size` is not `final`, the block size of output files in this TaskTracker will be `fs.local.block.size` in the client side. Because the job configuration will be commited to the TaskTracker.

If in this TaskTracker, `fs.local.block.size` is `final`, as `fs.local.block.size` can not be overrided by the job configuration, the block size in this TaskTracker  will be `fs.local.block.size` in the TaskTracker node. So in this situation, if your configuration is inconsistent in different nodes, you may find that the MapReduce output files have different block sizes.

The above analysis is only appropriate for `fs.local.block.size`. For other configuration, you may need to read the related source codes.

At last, I recommend that making all of your configurations consistent to avoid to trap in strange behaviours.